# Angular Error: NG0100 when a directive use @Input to access ElementRef in ng-container

Tags: javascript, angular

Minimal error version reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zlh4ri

explanation:

1. a component(comp1) use `<ng-container><span #viewEl></span></ng-container>`;
2. another component(comp2) use `<span #viewEl></span>`;
3. a commom directive try to access the `#viewEl` in 1/2 component;
4. comp1 raize a error: `NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '[object Object]'. Current value: 'undefined'`

How should I fix it?
(Allow change structure, but note that the directive should keep a copy of `viewEl` because I need it

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `ViewChild` in `Comp1` `static: true` to resolve query results before change detection runs.

```
@ViewChild('viewEl', { read: ElementRef, static: true })
```

Have a look at [the docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description) for more information.